# Which Angular2 Bootstrap is the "official" one?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am developing an Angular2 app with NG Bootstrap at https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, and current version is 1.0.0-alpha.20, available through npm.

And I had come across https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-bootstrap pointing to https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap, and current version is 1.1.16-1

Both Github projects look very active and providing the same set of components?

Which one should I use?

Comment: You didn't mention whether 1.1.16-1 is alpha or beta.  If it's beta, I'd recommend using the most current alpha version as you'd probably come across fewer issues, naturally.

Comment: apparently 1.1.16-1 is not alpha or beta.

Comment: ZZZ, have you sought clarification on Gitter?

Answer (score 1):

for me, i'll choose https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, it's seem support for IE and develop by AngularUI team, and AFAIK `ng2-bootstrap` break lazy load feature of Angular.